# Doctrine: How to get auto generated id after a merge ?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a legacy project in Symfony2, where mappings of entities are not correctly defined, but I would prefer not to touch them...

I got an entity with several ManyToOne relationships, but no cascade persist has been defined on these associations. And the associated entities also have relationships, and so on (the project is quite big)...

So, when I need to write a new entity to database, I usually use merge to avoid persisting all related entities:

```
$myObject = new Object();
...
$em->merge($myObject);
$em->flush();
```

But this time, I need to get the id of the inserted object. This id is auto generated by Doctrine (I also prefer not to change this).

I know that with persist, I can do:

```
$em->persist($object);
$em->flush();
$id = $object->getId();
```

But how can I do with merge ? Obviously this won't work:

```
$em->merge($object);
$em->flush();
$id = $object->getId(); // $id is null...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't want to use persist?

Comment: @goto Because I need to persist all related entities, and there is a lot, with recursivity. In fact I tried but I can't find a correct way to do it, I always end up to have an error like this: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyBundle\Object#field' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities):

> If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X’ of **the same identity**.

If you don't provide the ID of the entity you want to merge, Doctrine cannot merge it with an existing entity presents in your database.

If you always want to create a new entity, you can use `persist` instead of `merge` and use `getId()` in your entity.

If you really want to use `merge()`...

> If X is a new entity instance, **a new managed copy X’ will be created** and the state of X is copied onto this managed instance.

So, you have to use the new persisted entity returned by the merge.

```
$myDetachedObject = new Object();
// ...
$myAttachedObject = $em->merge($myDetachedObject);
$em->flush();

// $id = $myDetachedObject->getId(); // --> this won't work
$id = $myAttachedObject->getId();
```

Comment: $object = $em->merge($object);
$em->flush();

$id = $object->getId();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended doing:

```
$myObject = new Object();
...
$em->merge($myObject);
$em->flush();

// Get back object from db (merge doesn't give access to auto-generated id)
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Object')
    ->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->orderBy('o.id', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery();
$object = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

$id = $object->getId();
```

If someone has a better solution, please post it!

Comment: I have not used this before but some searched told me `$newEntity = $em->merge($entity);` then `$newEntity->getId()` should work.

Comment: This solution can, unfortunately, fail due to some other `Object` might have been stored into the database between persisting and fetching.